# Нахождение дубля и удаление с наименьшим значением

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

У меня имеется фрейм данных:

```
>>> df = {'full_name' : ['user1', 'user2','user3', 'user1'], 
      'timestamp': ['1617966829', '1617967400', '1614567432', '1617966941']}
>>> df

     full_name    timestamp
0        user1    1617966829
1        user2    1617967400
2        user3    1614567432
3        user1    1617966941
```

С помощью `df.duplicated` я получаю датафрейм содержащий дубли по столбцу `full_name`:

```
>>> df[df.duplicated(subset=['full_name'], keep = False)]

     full_name    timestamp
0        user1    1617966829
3        user1    1617966941
```

Я хочу удалить строку которая содержит наименьшее значение `timestamp`, но не могу понять как это сделать.

Как, и с помощью чего, могу удалить дубль строки по значению столбца `full_name` и с наименьшим значением `timestamp`?

Comment: а как должен выглядеть результат если в группе будет три (больше двух) строки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если дубликатов может быть больше двух, то, например, при исходных данных:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'full_name' : ['user1', 'user2','user3','user2', 'user1', 'user1'], 'timestamp': ['1617966942', '1617967400', '1614567432', '1617966941', '1617966829', '1617966829']})
```

df:

```
  full_name   timestamp
0     user1  1617966942
1     user2  1617967400
2     user3  1614567432
3     user2  1617966941
4     user1  1617966829
5     user1  1617966829
```

можно сделать так:

```
res = df.drop(df.index[df.loc[df.duplicated("full_name", keep=False)]
                       .sort_values("timestamp")
                       .groupby("full_name")
                       .apply(lambda x: x.index[0])])
```

тогда `res` бцдет:

```
  full_name   timestamp
0     user1  1617966942
1     user2  1617967400
2     user3  1614567432
5     user1  1617966829
```

Answer (score 1):

Если оставить нужно строки с максимальным `timestamp`:

```
res = df.groupby("full_name", as_index=False).max()
```

результат:

```
In [14]: res
Out[14]:
  full_name   timestamp
0     user1  1617966941
1     user2  1617967400
2     user3  1614567432
```

Comment: А если дублей больше двух?

Comment: @strawdog, ожидаю реакцию автора на [уточняющий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1268047/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc/1268053?noredirect=1#comment2230840_1268047) ;)

Comment: Если дублей больше двух, то также необходимо оставить строку с наибольшим значением timestamp

Comment: @Vasai, если в группе 3 строки - сколько строк должно остаться в результате - одна или две?

Comment: @MaxU, необходимо получить одну строку

Comment: @Vasai, тогда мой ответ `df.groupby("full_name", as_index=False).max()` полностью отвечает на ваш вопрос)

Comment: @Vasai, [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) ;)